# Removing elements from list

Tags: python, list

I have an array of length 900 and I want to remove the last 200 elements. I do not mind creating a new array but I want to code to be an concise and efficient as possible.

```
    f = [1,2,3,4,5,3,2,3,2,4,5,2....] #random one digit numbers of length 400. 
    t=400
    x=200
    while(t>x):
        f = np.delete(f,t)
        t = t-1
```

while this certainly works, I am looking for something that will preform the same task in less lines or at greater speed.

Comment: why not `f = f[:700]`

Comment: python has a slice mode!

Comment: That is not an array, that is a *list*.

Comment: Changed question title to better reflect the topic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also delete the elements without creating a new list:

```
del f[-200:]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use list slicing:

```
f = [1,2,3,4,5,3,2,3,2,4,5,2....]

f = f[:-200]
```